Uniform convergence and differentiation; difference between two theorems?
I am comparing two theorems in two different texts on uniform convergence and differentiability; the first one is from these lecture notes (page 9 in the pdf), the second from Rudin's PMA.
Here's the theorem from the lecture notes:

Theorem 9.18. Suppose that $(f_n)$ is a sequence of differentiable functions $f_n:(a,b)\to\mathbb R$ such that $f_n\to f$ pointwise and $f_n'\to g$ uniformly for some $f,g:(a,b)\to\mathbb R$. Then $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $f'=g$.

Here's Rudin's theorem:

7.17 Theorem Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions, differentiable on $[a,b]$ and such that $\{f_n(x_0)\}$ converges for some point $x_0$ on $[a,b]$. If $\{f_n'\}$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$, then $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$, to a function $f$, and $$f'(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n'(x)\quad (a\leq x\leq b).$$

Apart from working on open versus closed intervals, I struggle understanding the difference in the hypothesis of these two statements. Someone said the theorems are roughly equivalent, which I don't see how. From my point of view, Rudin's theorem assumes there's at least a single point $x_0$ in $[a,b]$ such that $(f_n(x_0))$ converges, whereas the first theorem seems to say we need convergence of $(f_n(x))$ for all $x$ in $(a,b)$.
Another thing is that Rudin's theorem concludes that $f_n\to f$ uniformly, whereas this is not concluded in the first theorem.
I am familiar with Rudin's definition of the derivative; the definition of the derivative in the lecture notes, as you may have guessed, uses open intervals. Maybe the difference in definitions matters somehow, I'm not sure.
I'd be grateful if someone could clarify the difference between these two theorems. Perhaps it is not sensible to compare them, or perhaps one is a special case of the other.

The short answer is that the second theorem is true, and the first theorem is a simplified corollary which the author has elected as the result he wanted his readers to study.

Personally, I like to remember it as the pair of theorems: "Let $I$ be an open interval of $\Bbb R$, let $f_n:I\to\Bbb R$ be a sequence of differentiable functions such that there is some $x_0\in I$ such that ${f_n(x_0)}{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges, and such that ${f'n}{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly on bounded (respectively, compact) subsets of $I$. Then, ${f_n}{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly on bounded (respectively, compact) subsets of $I$ to a differentiable function $f$ such that $\forall x\in I,\ f'(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f'_n(x)$."

The theorem you should know in your sleep is the Arzela-Ascoli theorem. Both of these theorems are straightforward consequences.

In Rudin's version, if you replace the closed interval with an open interval, you cannot prove uniform convergence. On any closed inverval inside the open interval, it converges uniformly, but the convergence may not be uniform as you approach the ends. Thus the author in the first theorem was required to assume uniform convergence from the outset, instead of proving it as in the second.

As pointed out in the comments, the first theorem can be viewed as a simplified version of the second theorem.
